# Android: many equal Buttons, onclick doesn't work for certain

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I have seven equal `Buttons` in `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="7" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_mon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white"        
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_tus"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="@color/white"        
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_wen"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="@color/white"        
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_thu"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="@color/white"        
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_fri"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="@color/white"        
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_sat"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="@color/white"        
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_sun"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="@color/white"       
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Their OnClickListener is also equal (and initializing too):

```
if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_row, null);
            }

final Button btn_mon = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mon);
final Button btn_tus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_tus);
final Button btn_wen = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_wen);
final Button btn_thu = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_thu);
final Button btn_fri = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_fri);
final Button btn_sat = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sat);
final Button btn_sun = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sun);

        btn_mon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v) { onCalBtnClick(btn_mon, weekdays.get(0).data); }});
        btn_tus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v) { onCalBtnClick(btn_tus, weekdays.get(1).data); }});
        btn_wen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v) { onCalBtnClick(btn_wen, weekdays.get(2).data); }});
        btn_thu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v) { onCalBtnClick(btn_thu, weekdays.get(3).data); }});
        btn_fri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v) { onCalBtnClick(btn_fri, weekdays.get(4).data); }});
        btn_sat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v) { onCalBtnClick(btn_sat, weekdays.get(5).data); }});
        btn_sun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v) { onCalBtnClick(btn_sun, weekdays.get(6).data); }});
```

onCalBtnClick method:

```
private void onCalBtnClick(Button btn, int day){            

            Log.d("debug", String.valueOf(day));
            btn.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
            //selectedYear, month are global
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("year", selectedYear);
            intent.putExtra("month", month);
            intent.putExtra("day", day);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
```

However, if I put `Log.d` into `onCalBtnClick` method (it is called from each `clicklistener`), only middle three buttons work. Two buttons from left side (*btn_mon*, *btn_tus*) and two buttons from right side (*btn_sat*, *btn_sun*) don't react on user click. Middle buttons work fine.

This is similar question [Android LinearLayout make button doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170248/android-linearlayout-make-button-doesnt-work) but my layout file corresponds to pattern in the answer there and buttons don't work nevertheless

**UPDATE**

When I removed fixed button height and width in layout file (from 50dp to wrap_content), all buttons started to work!

However, now it doesn't look as needed. There's space needed between text's on buttons.

And main question: **WHY?**

Comment: post how you initialize your btn_*

Comment: show your method onCalBtnClick, and try to log inside OnClick

Comment: added everything you asked

Comment: Does your buttons react on standard actions like hoover, pressed etc? I'm mean buttons graphics are changing?

Comment: @RvdK , it is parameter of `getView` method from my adapter which extends `BaseAdapter`. I added some init code to question

Comment: @piotrpo , button should change its text color when pressed. it works with three buttons: btn_wen, btn_thu, btn_fri . It is only one visual changing

Comment: Well I just wanted to know if there is e problem with code or layout definition. No reaction with some buttons means that there was not pressed (from adnroid point of view).

Comment: just a shot - try to change wrap_content to match_parent in linear_layout definition.

Comment: I have posted updated solution. Please check that.

Comment: Next shot - try to remove fixed width/height from your buttons.

Comment: @piotrpo second shot reached a goal. However, I don't understand why fixed sides affected the clickability! I updated my question

Comment: Glad to hear that. I've post my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using weights in your layout, you are telling that it should be filled with some objects with some proportions. It just opposite to "wrap_content". With weights outer layout defines size of inner views, while "wrap_content" means that outer layout size is defined by inner views.
Please decide what approach is better in that case - removing weights or fixed inner views sizes.

Answer (score 0):

set your Linear Layout's Width and Height to FILL_PARENT .it will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare all your setOnClickListener for buttons outside of your adapter class and after initialization of weekdays array.

That will solve your problem.

Or try to set condition like this for all buttons :

```
if (btn_mon != null && position < weekdays.size()) {
      btn_mon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v) { onCalBtnClick(btn_mon, weekdays.get(0).data); }});
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed that there is no nullPointException?

Comment: Its a safe side to check always while dealing with Adapter class. Adapter iterations play a vital role sometimes.